# Differentiating Specialized Structs based on signed-ness

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias, template-specialization

I need to be able to differentiate between data types which have the same sizes but different signed-ness properties. An example follows,

```
template <size_t N>
struct alias;

template<>
struct alias<sizeof(unsigned char)>{
    using Type = unsigned char;
};

template<>
struct alias<sizeof(signed char)>{
    using Type = signed char;
};

using uint8 = alias<1>::Type;
using int8 = alias<1>::Type;  //This is supposed to be signed type
```

Since first specialization uses unsigned char and both signed and unsigned chars use the same size, `alias<1>::Type`results returning unsigned char. But I want to be able to return same data type as both signed and unsigned.

I am also aware there are std::is_signed or std::is_unsigned under type_traits header file. I could not figure out how to use them in this context.

**EDIT**

Partial Complete Code

```
#define BYTE 1

template <size_t N>
struct alias;

#define REGISTER_ALIAS(X)           \
template <>                         \
struct alias <sizeof(X)> {          \
           using Type = X;          \
};

REGISTER_ALIAS(unsigned char)
REGISTER_ALIAS(signed char)

using int8 = alias<BYTE>::Type;
using uint8 = alias<BYTE>::Type;
```

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do with this `alias` struct? What's the context you're planning on using it in?

Comment: Creating fix-width data types without hardcoded typedefs.

Comment: Sounds like you just want another template parameter.

Comment: I actually tried using another template parameter but could not get it to work in this context. I may have missed something.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried, and why it didn't work as you wanted?

Comment: It actually works, only thing left to accomplish is just to be able to differentiate between signed and unsigned types.

Comment: I've already implemented what youre trying to do. I added an enum template parameter for signness

Comment: @Kerndog73 Could you provide some examples as to how you used enum template parameter to accomplish the task? I have shared part of my code now.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did.

```
enum Sign {
  SIGNED,
  UNSIGNED
};

template <size_t SIZE, Sign SIGN>
struct Alias;

template <>
struct Alias<1, SIGNED> {
  using type = int8_t;
};
//etc
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it still requires hardcoding. I want everything to be deduced by the compiler including signed-ness. You first mark the template to be SIGNED by hand and alias signed value. I want the given value to be marked as signed or unsigned by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what do you want.

But I suppose that you have to explicit, in some way, that you want a signed type or an unsigned type.

I propose the following way, based on a couple of different types and an explicit selection

```
template <size_t N>
struct alias;

template<>
struct alias<sizeof(char)>{
    using sType = signed char;
    using uType = unsigned char;
};

using uint8 = alias<1>::uType;
using int8 = alias<1>::sType;
```

Comment: For example, I can specialize the alias struct with both unsigned and signed chars without any problem during compilation. Assuming char is only 1 byte, calling alias<1>::Type returns whatever alias specialization for char data type is defined first although there are two specializations. I wanna be able to use both signed and unsigned chars specialization. Basically there are two specializations that corresponds to 1. Is there a way for me to use both?

Comment: @nomadov - I don't know how; how can the compiler understand when using the signed version and when the unsigned one?